# Difference between O(log n) and O(log n +1)

Tags: time-complexity

I find time and space complexity very confusing (if there are any easy to understand blogs/videos feel
free to link it).

Does the +1 there make a difference in case of time complexity? or is O(log n) considered the same as O(log n + 1)?

Answer (score 2):

Additive and multiplicative constants never matter. For all constants *M*≠0 and *A*, *O*(*M* ⋅ *f*(*n*) + *A*) = *O*(*f*(*n*)).

Comment: This is true so long as f(n) is not in o(1), as in little o rather than big O. Otherwise the constant term *A* will dominate.

Comment: what about O(nlogn) where n is being multiplied and not a random constant? would it still be equivalent to O(logn)?

Comment: No, it only works for constants.

Answer (score 0):

When you are calculating the Big O notation, the Constants do not really matter, As we are calculating the speed at which something will grow, Having a constant here will be completely irrelevant with a large input.

Assuming having two algorithms for sorting with `O(n)` and `O(n^2)`, given an input of `n=50`

Now assuming that we do have a constant for the `O(n)` of `500` and another constant for `O(n^2)` of `5`

```
O(n) = 50 * 500 = 25000

O(n^2) = 50 * 50 * 5 = 12500
```

for this case, the O(n^2) is actually faster, But assuming we have n = 1,000,000 for example

```
O(n) = 1,000,000 * 500 = 500,000,000 

O(n^2) = 1,000,000 * 1,000,000 * 5 = 5,000,000,000,000
```

So as you can see, as the input gets larger and larger the gap will grow, and therefore the constant does not really matter in the Big O notation calculations.